# Compare proccess.env.NODE_ENV with String

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

Why when I compare those two I get `false`

```
const production = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
```

Even when I set `process.env.NODE_ENV` to production I still get `false` value.

Why?

Example:

package.json SCRIPTS:

```
"scripts": {
    "start:prod": "set NODE_ENV=production && nodemon server.js"
}
```

VS CODE

```
const production = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';

console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV); // production
console.log(typeof process.env.NODE_ENV); // string
console.log(typeof 'production'); // string
console.log(production) // false
```

Why production returns false even though the values are exactly the same?

Answer (score 3):

To set node environment in powershell use below:

$env:NODE_ENV = 'production'

drop the spaces before and after &&

```
"scripts": {
    "start:prod": "set NODE_ENV=production&&nodemon server.js"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this

```
"scripts": {
    "start:prod": "NODE_ENV=production nodemon server.js"
}
```

`set` command is used to set or unset values of shell options and positional parameters and not the environment variables

Answer (score 0):

I met the similar issue and it took me a couple of hours to realize this.

Your `package.json` has this script

```
"scripts": {
    "start:prod": "set NODE_ENV=production && nodemon server.js"
}
```

However you should not that your comparison should return false becouse your env you set in the script contains space  here `production &&`

To be able to return true you should remove that space and your script should look like this.

```
"scripts": {
    "start:prod": "set NODE_ENV=production&& nodemon server.js"
}
```

Keep your comparison expression it is ok for it.

Answer (score 0):

It works if you use `includes` instead of the equality operator

```
process.env.NODE_ENV.includes('production') // true
```