# Javascript object returns undefined with proper key

Tags: javascript, express, object

I'm trying to make an express application and doing some performance improvements for production. I tried to follow this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WiZ2Py97rio. He has a config object with the keys: 'development', 'production' & 'test'.

I copied that as follows:

```js
import bunyan from "bunyan";

const loggers = {
    development: () => bunyan.createLogger({name: "development", level: "debug"}),
    production: () => bunyan.createLogger({name: "production", level: "info"}),
    test: () => bunyan.createLogger({name: "test", level: "fatal"}),
}

const config = {
    development: {
        log: loggers.development
    },
    production: {
        log: loggers.production
    },
    test: {
        log: loggers.test
    }
};

export default config;
```

When using it as follows it only works in development:

```js
import configObject from "./config.js";
const config = configObject[process.env.NODE_ENV || "development"];
const log = config.log();
```

In production when I run these:

```js
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV || "development");
console.log(configObject);
console.log(configObject[process.env.NODE_ENV || "development"]);
```

This is the output:

```bash
production 

{
  development: { log: [Function: development] },
  production: { log: [Function: production] },
  test: { log: [Function: test] }
}

undefined
```

So it knows it's in production, the configObject has the key production but the config evaluates to false. Anybody knows why this is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't reproduce. Do you perhaps have some trailing whitespace or non-ascii characters in the word `production`?

Comment: Try some basic debugging. Try copy-pasting the object key to your environment variable or vice versa and see if it still happens. That's quite unintuitive behavior.

Comment: Are you sure you saved `config.js`? Perhaps you only typed in the object key for development but not production before you saved it.

Comment: try by initializing like const current_env = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development" and then const config = configObject[current_env ]

Comment: @BrijeshDave already tried that, no luck :(

Comment: @code yep, it's all saved

Edit: Also you can see when I print the config object it does print out the production and test objects aswell

Comment: Well, try all sorts of different things. Try `Object.keys(config)[1] === process.env.NODE_ENV`.

Comment: @code Object.keys(configObject) returns:
`
[ 'development', 'production', 'test' ]
`

Comment: Yes, can you verify that it's strictly equal to `process.env.NODE_ENV`?

Comment: Both strict and non-strict dont evaluate to true, unless it's development. The code only works when NODE_ENV is development for some reason...

Comment: Okay I found the issue... Feel really stupid for not looking this up earlier: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62675738/compare-proccess-env-node-env-with-string

Answer (score 0):

So I found that the issue was with my production script. I had `"win-production": "SET NODE_ENV=production && node ./src/server.js | bunyan -o short",` But the space after production was taken into account for.

Fixed thanks to: [Compare proccess.env.NODE_ENV with String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62675738/compare-proccess-env-node-env-with-string)